# Relative risk aversion and lotteries exercise

Tags: microeconomics, risk, risk-aversion

> Given a consumer with a utility function, $u(w)$, and a wealth of $w>1000$. Assuming that the consumers relative risk aversion is constant and equal to 1, that is $R_r(w)=1$ for $w>0$, the consumer is facing a lottery that gives him 50% chance to win 1000 and 50% chance to lose 1000.

My question is, how much is the consumer willing to pay to avoid this lottery, and how does it depend on $w$? I can't seem to figure it out, and I really have no idea where to start.

Comment: Start [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Risk_aversion#Relative_risk_aversion). Than graph your `u(w)`. Make sure that w>1000 is a correct condition. It seems strange. May be, u(w) is defined on w>0 and his/her current wealth is a point in a range w>1000?

Comment: $u(w)$ is defined for $w>0$ - his current wealth is $w>1000$ when he is facing the lottery. Sorry I didn't make that clear :)

I'll have a look at your link, thanks.

Comment: You should edit your question, and my comment will be redundant. And do not forget to carefully read site rules =))

Answer (score 2):

You want the household to be *ex-ante* indifferent between taking the lottery and paying some $p$ and voiding it.

With van-Neumann-Morgenstein utility, the utility of taking the lottery is given by $$U_L(w) \equiv 0.5 U(w-1000) + 0.5U(w+1000)$$

Now, you're looking for a payment $p(w)$ such that $u(w - p(w)) = U_L(w)$.